# Class A creates 2 instances of Class B. How to access item from Class B(1) from inside class B?

Tags: java, android, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I have a sectioned recycler view with 2 sections. They hold shopping list items in a recycler view, each item has a checkbox. I am using this library for sections:
https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

I am trying to set an onCheckedChangeListener for the checkboxes so if an item in section 1 becomes checked, it goes to section 2 and visa versa when checked->unchecked. I am starting with just trying to delete an item from section 1 when checked.

The ShoppingList class (Class A) creates the 2 instances of the HeaderRecyclerViewSection (Class B).

**Shopping List class:**

```
public class ShoppingList extends AppCompatActivity {
HeaderRecyclerViewSection firstSection = new HeaderRecyclerViewSection("Unchecked", getDataSource());
HeaderRecyclerViewSection secondSection = new HeaderRecyclerViewSection("Checked", getDataSource());

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// shopping list with sections
    sectionHeader = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.shopping_listView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ShoppingList.this);
    sectionHeader.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    sectionHeader.setHasFixedSize(true);

    sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();
    sectionAdapter.addSection(firstSection);
    sectionAdapter.addSection(secondSection);
    sectionHeader.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
}
```

**Section Class:**

I need something in the onCheckedChangeListener to get the item that was clicked and remove it from the `firstSection`, then notify the adapter in Shopping List.

```
public class HeaderRecyclerViewSection extends StatelessSection{
private static final String TAG = HeaderRecyclerViewSection.class.getSimpleName();
private String title;
public List<ShoppingItem> list;
public HeaderRecyclerViewSection(String title, List<ShoppingItem> list) {
    super(SectionParameters.builder()
            .itemResourceId(R.layout.shopping_item)
            .headerResourceId(R.layout.section_header)
            .build());
    this.title = title;
    this.list = list;
}
@Override
public int getContentItemsTotal() {
    return list.size();
}

public boolean addItem(ShoppingItem shoppingItem) {
    return list.add(shoppingItem);
}

public boolean removeItem(ShoppingItem shoppingItem) {
    return list.remove(shoppingItem);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ItemViewHolder iHolder = (ItemViewHolder)holder;
    final ShoppingItem currentItem = list.get(position);
    iHolder.itemContent.setText(currentItem.getItemName());

    iHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        removeItem(currentItem); 

        }
    });
}
```

**ItemViewHolder:**

```
public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
public TextView itemContent;
public CheckBox checkBox;
public Button deleteButton;
public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemContent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    checkBox = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    deleteButton = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteItem);
}
```

}

Comment: So you need to remove HeaderRecyclerViewSection instance from ShoppingList?

Comment: I need to remove an item from one of the HeaderRecyclerViewSections

Comment: To "delete" an object, you just need to set it to null or let it fall out of scope. The garbage collector (`System.gc()`) will take care of it.

Comment: How would I access the other list inside the onCheckedChange? I have to delete and then add it to the other list, or move it somehow

Comment: yes it can be done...post your adapter class...

Comment: these are the 2 classes I have, I am using https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter Library.       Edit: I have Header and item view holder classes too

Comment: you need a reference of firstSection in secondSection and vice versa, so you can call the removeItem method.. there are many ways of doing it, easiest way would be to add a variable in your HeaderRecyclerViewSection called "otherSection" and a setter method for it. Then in your ShoppingList class you do `firstSection.setOtherSection(secondSection)` and vice versa.. then in your onCheckedChanged you call `otherSection.removeItem`.. then you have to call the `notifyDataSetChanged` of your sectionAdapter